# Error #1064 on DB Import via PHPMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am using:

mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.31-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2

I have a wordpress db that I am trying to migrate from one dev environment to another, but I am getting this error when I try to import the db to the new location via phpmyadmin.

[image]

Does anyone know how I can resolve this? thx

**How I made my dump.sql file:**
1.) in the PMA for my old multisite installation (functioning, no problems), I login as a superuser (not root) that I created that has global GRANT ALL privileges on all dbs.

2.) I create a new dbuser that matches the dbuser on my target (new) multisite, -without- a default db.

3.) Then, I select the old multisite in pma -> operations and copy the desired db to a new db that has the same name as the user that I just created in step two

4.) **THIS IS WHEN THINGS GET WEIRD** After the new db has been created, inside pma I go to user accounts so that I can grant my new user all privileges on the new db.  That's when I notice something weird in the title of db, that wasn't in the title of db when I used this same process to successfully migrate a different multisite. Screenshot:
[image]

For reasons, unbeknownst to me, PMA is adding a "" to the dbname. And just to confirm, the name is shown correctly on previous screen:
[image]

When I go back to pm -> user accounts -> databases, this is what I see:

[image]

5.) If I ignore the weird name and export the db to a .sql file,  I get the error seen above, when I try to import.

Comment: Did you check that the dump you have is actually valid? This looks like you are trying to import a html page - possibly an error message instead of the dump.

Comment: The file which you want to import in HTML page, not a dump.

Comment: @jkavalik  I added more information to my post to show how I created the .sql file and where I think the error came from

Comment: @Akina   I added more information to my post to show how I created the .sql file and where I think the error came from

Comment: been tinkering, my additional info, may be totally useless.  @jkavalik how can I check the validity after the sql export?  And confirming for everyone.. I am exporting a SQL format file.  I don't know why PMA thinks I am importing an html file

Comment: *I added more information to my post to show how I created the .sql file* This is not interesting. Simply open your file in any text editor and ensure that it contains SQL statements really and not HTML code (like MySQL reports).

Comment: @jkavalik thanks

Comment: I don't follow what you mean by the step _Then, I select the old multisite in pma -> operations and copy the desired db to a new db that has the same name as the user that I just created in step two_: phpMyAdmin won't copy between database servers, and this won't generate a .sql file. Could you please tell us how you created this SQL file?

Comment: _For reasons, unbeknownst to me, PMA is adding a \ to the dbname._ Yes, this is correct on that screen; since the underscore is a wildcard character to MySQL, phpMyAdmin mostly hides the escape character \ from the user for normal operations, but when defining privileges it must be quite precise because sometimes users mean a literal underscore and sometimes they mean the wildcard character. Putting the escape character in the page there is meant to help remove any confusion (although it seems to also cause some there).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the assistance. The comment from @jkavalik above, led me to this posts:

[phpmyadmin exports an .sql file that contains html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54185242/phpmyadmin-exports-an-sql-file-that-contains-html) (Stack Overflow)

Which explains that the easiest way to resolve the problem is to use command line to export the database, because my multisite has a large database.

```bash
mysqldump -u username -p db_name > dumpfile.sql
```

then:

```bash
mysql -u user -p db_name < dumpfile.sql
```